# JS inside <body> not working on FF 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, firefox4

I have a website I'm working on, and in FF4 the JS that is located inside the body of the page doesn't work.  You can view it here: http://www.1tryten.com/products/Laptop-Lock-Pro.html

Any JS in the head works, but not the body.  You can replicate the problem by trying to add this item to the cart or clicing write a review.  Try it in IE or Chrome and it works...

It works on all other browsers.  Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: Can you simplify your page to minimal example that reproduce the error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

> Error: missing ) after argument list
>   Source File: `http://www.1tryten.com/products/Laptop-Lock-Pro.html`
>   Line: 933, Column: 50
>   Source Code:
>
> ```
> $('#subscribe_form').append("<input type="hidden" name="check" value="1" />"); 
> // ---------------------------------------^
> ```

You can debug your code easily by having a look at the console (Tools -> Error Console).

It don't think it will work in Chrome or IE either.

Another error I get:

> Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object"  code: "15" nsresult: "0x8053000f (NS_ERROR_DOM_INVALID_ACCESS_ERR)"  location: "http://www.1tryten.com/javascript/common.js?1 Line: 779"]

Comment: using firebug for firefox is also a good way to inspect elements and debug javascript

Comment: That looks like it's coming from inside that "Preload CSS Images" plugin where it tries to touch the CSS stylesheet elements.

Answer (score 3):

You have error in code See `"` and `'` !

This:

```
$('#subscribe_form').append("<input type="hidden" name="check" value="1" />");
```

should be:

```
$('#subscribe_form').append('<input type="hidden" name="check" value="1" />');
```

Comment: @Ben: I guess will get better help if you explain what is the expected behaviour and what actually happens.